# How to scroll form panel at top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sencha-touch

I am working on a sencha touch mobile app. There is one form panel having many fields so I kept it as scrollable. when I open that screen (panel) and scroll down. and go back to other screens and again come back to that screen panel, it remains scrolled down at bottom position. I want to always set it at the top when I will open it. I have tried some code on activate event of that form, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I have tried to belove code in the activate event.

```
         this.formPan.element.dom.scrollTo('top', 0);
            //this.formPan.reset();
            //Ext.getCmp('mainscreenpanelId').element.dom.parentElement.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)'
            //--3rd commented line of code works, but after activate/on focus form again it comes to last scrolled position--
```

also, I checked if any method is there to scroll at the top, but didn't found.
Is there any way to do that.

below images more discribing my issue, screen is default when we open form first time
[image]

2nd Image remain srolled at bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I have used window.scrollTo(0, 0) to scroll screen always top. 
>   Try this.